# Dynamodb CPU utlization

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb

I am using Nodejs with Dynamodb/Dynamoose for one of application which has very high concurrent users requirement. I am seeing some really unusual amounts of traffic on it. When I tried to do similar thing with Mongodb/Mongoose I got a much lower CPU usage. Has anyone used Dynamodb for highly concurrent traffic? If so what was the CPU utilization pattern that they have seen in that?

Comment: try to use aws-sdk without dynamoose and let me know

Comment: @varnit I did...... The difference is marginal

Comment: Dynamoose is a new library it might be slow you can use dynamodb document client to save json directly to dynamo db if dynamoose is not a hardcore requirement and aws sdk also has advantage of great community support and better documentation